# Conflicts using Tkinter/wxPython with Python AddIn scripting?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, tkinter, wxpython

I want to design a custom dialog window where i can select various datasets of choice using scroll down option and specify some conditions and thresholds. Right now i am using python addins within arcgis 10.1 for toolbar and tools. I came across tkinter and wxpython as options for dialog box designing. Will there be a conflict between using tkinter or wxpython within addin scripting?

Comment: A wxPython example is here: [Custom wxPython GUI’s: an approach for ArcGIS 10.1](http://betablogs.esri.com/beta/arcgis/2012/05/03/custom-wxpython-guis-an-approach-for-arcgis-10-1/)

Comment: @blah238 It looks like your link is broken - perhaps you have an updated one that you could add as an answer alongside mine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a technique to do this described at Another GIS Blog under the title of [Python Add-Ins and Tkinter](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/python-add-ins-and-tkinter.html):

> ArcGIS for Desktop does not support any python GUIs out of the box,
>   but let's say we want to have a form pop-up anyway. ...
>
> One way to do this is to create a wx python instance at start up,
>   which is create before the desktop python loop is created.  You would
>   then reference the wx loop instead of the ArcGIS python loop.. but
>   it's complicated...  You can also see tons of forum posts like this,
>   that describe how the in process causes python to crash with GUIs:
>   [ArcGIS 10.1 Python AddIn Using Multiprocessing crashes ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36848/crashing-arcgis-10-1-add-ins-using-multiprocessing)